# curl package not loaded at ghci

Tags: windows, haskell, curl

After installing successfully (and painfully) curl-1.3.7 , i have the following error when i fire up ghci (using argument -package curl)

```
Loading package curl-1.3.7 ... ghc.exe: Unknown PEi386 section name `.drectve' (while processing: C:\curl-7.26.0\lib\libcurl.a)
```

i'm under windows 7 and i'm using the last haskell platform (2012).

I followed the procedure at http://haskell.forkio.com/Home/curl-win32, and try sequentially the package provided (curl 7.19.4) and curl 7.26(mingw64)

Comment: does this make a difference: (mingw `64`) and curl-`win32`?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be related to GHC bug 7103: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7103

see here: [How to resolve the GHC error "Unknown PEi386 section name `.idata$4' " on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13209425/371753)

Discussion here suggests linking against a dll if possible: https://github.com/lpsmith/postgresql-libpq/issues/7