# How to resolve the GHC error "Unknown PEi386 section name `.idata$4' " on Windows?

Tags: x86, ghc, portable-executable, unix-ar, dlltool

I recently found out that [instructions I had written](https://github.com/hdbc/hdbc-postgresql/wiki/WindowsInstall) to compile HDBC-postgresql on Windows were no longer working with Haskell Platform 2012.2.0.0. The library builds alright, but when attempting to link the built library, `cabal` fails with:

```
Loading package HDBC-postgresql-2.3.2.1 ... ghc.exe: Unknown PEi386 section name
 `.idata$4' (while processing: C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/9.2/lib\libpq.a)
ghc.exe: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
  (GHC version 7.4.1 for i386-unknown-mingw32):
        loadArchive "C:/PROGRA~1/POSTGR~1/9.2/lib\\libpq.a": failed
```

I tried re-making `libpq.a` with `dlltool --no-idata4 --no-idata5`, but then the error message changed to `` Unknown PEi386 section name `.idata$7' ``.

This seems to be [GHC bug 7103](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7103).

According to the [PE and COFF Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx), the dollar sign has a special meaning when included in section names, signaling a "grouped section". The linker is supposed to discard the "$" and all characters that follow it to create a merged `.idata` section, where the characters following the "$" are used to determine the ordering of contributions to the merged section.

Is there a way to force `dlltool` to not output grouped sections?

Alternatively, is there a way to take a GNU archive (A file), merge all grouped sections, and output the resulting merged import library (implib)?

**EDIT:** The same error happens with Haskell Platform 2012.4.0.0.

**EDIT2** After looking at [the source code of `dlltool`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils.git;a=blob;f=binutils/dlltool.c), there doesn't appear to be a way to force it not to output grouped sections. Also, I haven't found a ready-built utility that will merge grouped sections in an object file.

For the purpose of the bounty and this question, I am changing it to: How to construct a single `.idata` section given a module definition (DEF) file.

Comment: try to link with dll directly instead of linking with import library

Answer (score 1):

> The linker is supposed to discard the "$" and all characters that follow it to create a merged .idata section

Yes, but that's only the default behavior of the Microsoft linker.  I'm not up to speed enough on your tool-chain so just some hints.  The gcc linker requires explicit config to merge the various .idata$x sections into a single .idata section.  That's done by the SECTION directive.  In mingw that appears to be done by a script, a sample one is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/uric/pyneuron/src/d65f9c5cf37c/home/i686-pc-mingw32/lib/ldscripts/i386pe.xbn).  Note this part of the script:

```
  .idata BLOCK(__section_alignment__) :
  {
    /* This cannot currently be handled with grouped sections.
        See pe.em:sort_sections.  */
    SORT(*)(.idata$2)
    SORT(*)(.idata$3)
    /* These zeroes mark the end of the import list.  */
    LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0); LONG (0);
    SORT(*)(.idata$4)
    __IAT_start__ = .;
    SORT(*)(.idata$5)
    __IAT_end__ = .;
    SORT(*)(.idata$6)
    SORT(*)(.idata$7)
  }
```

Pretty inscrutable but the shoe fits.  Make sure that your linker uses such a script.

Comment: My guess is, you're right that this has something to do with it. I looked for a linker script in the Haskell Platform folder, but I could not find one. Thank you very much for this information. I didn't realize that a linker script is involved behind the scenes when linking a binary using MinGW.